# Prove $B(p,q) + B(p+1,q) + B(p+2,q) + ... = B(p,q-1) $ where $B$ is beta function and $q > 1$

Tags: analysis, special-functions

Prove $B(p,q) + B(p+1,q) + B(p+2,q) + ... = B(p,q-1) $ where $B$ is beta function and $q > 1$.

I tried with some basic formulas for beta function, mathematical induction but just cannot get some good idea and solve this. If anyone have some idea, please help. I will be grateful.

Comment: Using the integral representation of the beta function for the LHS allows a geometric series to be found which when added I assume gives the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

$$B(p,q) + B(p+1,q) + B(p+2,q) + ...=\int_0^1 t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1}dt+\int_0^1 t^{p}(1-t)^{q-1}dt+\int_0^1 t^{p+1}(1-t)^{q-1}dt+...$$
$$=\int_0^1 (t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1}+t^{p}(1-t)^{q-1}+t^{p+1}(1-t)^{q-1}+...)dt$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1}}{1-t} dt$$
$$=\int_0^1 t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-2} dt$$
$$=B(p,q-1)$$

Comment: The simplification in the third to last line comes from the fact that an infinite geometric series with initial term $a$ and common ratio $r$ has a value of $\frac{a}{1-r}$. The initial term here is $t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1}$ and the common ratio is $t$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I got it :)

Comment: Note that his proof assumes you can interchange the order of summation and integration, because it brings the (outer) sum into the expression inside the integral.  I'm pretty sure this requires some convergence conditions, but the basic idea is in place in this answer (as well as in mine).

Answer (score -1):

By definition, starting from the LHS of your problem,
$$
\sum_{n=p}^\infty\beta(n,q) = \sum_{n=p}^\infty\int_0^1t^{n-1}(1-t)^{q-1}dt 
$$
Since $t$ is always in $[0,1]$ things converge nicely (I think uniformly) and we are free to interchange integral and sum:
$$
\sum_{n=p}^\infty\beta(n,q) = \int_0^1\sum_{n=p}^\infty t^{n-1}(1-t)^{q-1}dt 
$$
Again, for this range of $t$, the sums converge:
$$
\sum_{n=p}^\infty t^{n-1}(1-t)^{q-1} = t^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^\infty t^{m}(1-t)^{q-1}
= t^{p-1}\frac1{1-t}(1-t)^{q-1}=  t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-2}
$$
Finally, placing this back into the integral, we have
$$
\sum_{n=p}^\infty\beta(n,q) =  \int_0^1t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-2}dt =\beta(p,q-1)
$$

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? Because of the loose argumentation for interchanging sum and  integral?